# Why can't I get online graphing software to plot $r=\cos^{0.18}(3\theta)$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: polar-coordinates

So I know in polar coordinates the function such as $\cos (2 \theta)$ can be easily mapped and furthermore can be mapped on graphing softwares such as [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com) or [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com).

But how come these softwares will not let me graph polar functions like $\cos^{0.18}(3\theta)$?

Comment: have you tried using the syntax in desmos:  $(\cos(3\theta))^{0.18}$ ?

Comment: What is the intervall for $\theta?$ Remember that $(\cos3\theta)^{0.18}$ is complex for $\theta > \pi/4 = 30° \approx 0.53 $

Comment: On Desmos,click on the wrench on upper right to display the graph setting. On second row (beneath the grid, above the arrows radio boxes) there are two cricle, one of them is to draw graph in polar form. select that and then type `r = cos(3theta)^0.18` in the input box.  On WA, either `polar plot r = cos(3*t)^0.18` or `PolarPlot[Cos[3*t]^0.18,{t,-Pi,Pi}]` will draw the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patrick was right in his comment; Desmos is perfectly happy to graph $r_1=(\cos(3\theta))^{0.18}$, but it won't graph $r_2=\cos^{0.18}(3\theta)$, even though a human being would likely understand what you mean by the second form. Desmos will only graph functions involving terms of the form $\cos^{\hspace{0.4mm}n}(x)$ and/or $\sin^n(x)$ if $n=2$ or $n=-1$ (and in the latter case, Desmos assumes you want the inverse sine or cosine functions, which may not necessarily be true).

For reference:

[image]

Wolfram Alpha has similar preferences; it tends to prefer functions of the form that $r_1$ is in, no matter to what exponent you want to raise a sine or cosine.